# Update record in SQL through PHP

Tags: php

how can i update the record from database?

```
$query = "UPDATE studentinfo SET firstname= '".$student['fname']."' and lastname='".$student['faname']."' and gender = 'Male' WHERE id = '".$student['id']."'";
```

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement seems like a reasonable way to start.  Is something not working?  Can you maybe provide *some* information about the problem?  (Also, be aware that this code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.)

Comment: i want to update a student record in db but my query is not working properly.

Comment: Oh hi, my name is `bob'; DROP TABLE studentinfo; --`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating records in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287350/updating-records-in-database)

Comment: @phpisuber01 is trying to demonstrate that this code makes it very easy to delete the complete table, or do other evil things, using SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more information.

Comment: want to update through form.:(

Comment: Are you paying by the keystroke for your internet? You need to put more effort into your question.

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = 'value1', column2 = 'value2'
```

Do not use AND to separate terms in the SET clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "UPDATE studentinfo SET firstname= '".$student['fname']."', lastname='".$student['faname']."', gender = 'Male' WHERE id = '".$student['id']."'";
```

Comment: i want to get id from auto increament.but not geting through $_get method

Comment: That's a matter for another question, feel free to make it and link to it, but ONLY if you make the question become better than this one. Read about how to post questions on stackoverflow, please.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is used in `SQL` for multiple-conditions.

To update multiple fields just separate them with a comma:

```
$query ="UPDATE studentinfo 
SET firstname = '$student['fname']', lastname = '$student['faname']', gender = 'Male'
WHERE id = '$student['id']'";
```